# How to use react-native-web with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-web

I've created the application using `create-react-native-app`. Commands which I use to run and make production build are:

```
"scripts": {
  "web": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build"
}
```

For react native I can use `react-native-scripts-ts`, but how to configure Typescript pipeline with react-native-web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to use:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "web": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-native-scripts-ts build",
    "test:web": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

And run `App.tsx` with:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent("root", () => App);
AppRegistry.runApplication('root', { rootTag: document.getElementById('root') });
```